# How can we tell from looking at a problem that multiplication principle fails to solve it? And why does MP fail(?) in the first place?

Tags: combinatorics

> Three officers—a president, a treasurer, and a secretary— are to be chosen from among four people: Ann, Bob, Cyd, and Dan. Suppose that Bob is not qualified to be treasurer and Cyd’s other commitments make it impossible for her to be secretary. How many ways can the officers be chosen?

There are $14$ ways the officers can be chosen.

No matter how we try, MP can't be applied to this problem? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects to be chosen are not interchangeable ("Bob" can't go in the "treasurer" slot while the others can, and "Cyd" can't go in the "secretary" slot while the others can).

If all objects were equally able to go in any slot, you'd have $4\times 3\times 2=24$ ways of choosing, which I assume is the approach you refer to with the phrase "multiplication principle".

Comment: But if we restate the problem as " Three officers—a president, a treasurer, and a secretary—are to be chosen from among four people: Ann, Bob, Cyd, and Dan. Suppose that, for various reasons, Ann cannot be president and either Cyd or Dan must be secretary. How many ways can the officers be chosen? ", we can use multiplication. Can you, please, elaborate on that.

Comment: The manner in which you phrase the non-interchangeability (e.g., *"alien overlords have decreed that Bob cannot be a secretary"*) is **irrelevant to the mathematics**. If not all objects have the same options available to them, you then have to keep track of which objects goes in what slot.

Comment: So, how do we solve the 2nd problem by multiplication? Would "There are three choices for president (all except Ann), three choices for treasurer (all except the one chosen as president), and two choices for secretary (Cyd or Dan). Therefore, by the multiplication rule, there are 3·3·2 = 18 choices in all." be correct?

Comment: The point of my answer is that you **can't** "solve by multiplication". Here's a simpler case: I have two boxes labeled `1` and `2`. I have three letters, `A`, `B`, and `C`, and I want to put one letter in each box. If I make no restrictions on what can go where, then my options are (`A`, `B`, or `C` for the first box) $\times$ (whichever two are left for the second box) = $3\times 2$ = $6$. However, if I declare that `C` cannot go in box `2`, then it is incorrect to say *"whichever two are left"* because sometimes there **aren't** two left that can go in box two.

Comment: In fact, the possibilities are `1[A] 2[B]` (only **one** option remains if I put `A` in `1`) or `1[B] 2[A]` (only **one** option remains if I put `B` in `1`) or `1[C] 2[A]` or `1[C] 2[B]` (**two** options remain if I put `C` in `1`).

Comment: I was told I *can* solve this problem by multiplication if I reorder the way I choose the officers: choose the secretary first, then president, then treasurer. 2 * 2 * 2 = 8 in all. I am majorly confused.

Comment: If you choose the secretary first, you have 3 options: `Ann`, `Bob`, `Dan`, so I already have no idea where you're getting a 2 from. Moreover, note that if you choose `Bob` for secretary then you have **3 options** for treasurer whereas if you choose `Ann` or `Dan` for secretary then you have **2 options** for treasurer (since it cannot be `Bob`) - that's the non-interchangeability in action.

Comment: I am solving the second redefined problem in my first comment: " Three officers—a president, a treasurer, and a secretary—are to be chosen from among four people: Ann, Bob, Cyd, and Dan. Suppose that, for various reasons, Ann cannot be president and either Cyd or Dan must be secretary. How many ways can the officers be chosen? "